# C++ stringstream output performance

Tags: c++, performance, stringstream

I tested the following two code snippets and found that code snippet A was more efficient than code snippet B. Why? `str()` has copy operations but `rdbuf()` don't. Is `str("")` is more expensive than `str()`?

code snippet A:

```
ofstream out("foo.txt");
stringstream ss;
for(int i = 0; i < 300000; i++) {
    // append long text to ss
    out<<ss.str();
    ss.seekp(ios_base::beg);
}
out.close();
```

code snippet B:

```
ofstream out("foo.txt");
stringstream ss;
for(int i = 0; i < 300000; i++) {
    // append long text to ss
    out<<ss.rdbuf();
    ss.str("");
}
out.close();
```

Comment: You are mixing two comparisons here: `out<<ss.str()` vs `out<<ss.rdbuf()` _and_ `ss.seekp(ios_base::beg)` vs `ss.str("")`. And the first is even more complex, because there's in the same statement a call to a member function (`str` or `rdbuf`) _plus_ an output (`<<`) with 2 different types (`string` or `filebuf*`)...

Comment: @gx_ I understand ss.str() means copy and ss.str("") means replacing. So the point is whether replacing is more expensive than copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two potential differences can be detected:

`out<<ss.str();` copies the data as `std::basic_string`, where `out<<ss.rdbuf();` returns a pointer of type `std::basic_streambuf<CharT,Traits>`

`ss.str("");` replaces the content in the stringstream, where `ss.seekp(ios_base::beg);` only sets the output position indicator

ps.

`ss.str("")` and `ss.str()` are two different operations.
See:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str

Comment: That line by itself shouldn't be that expensive when compared to the rest of the operations though. Personally I would be hesitant to say that the two ways of writing the output are almost equal. Without having looked to deeply into the issue I would think that `out<<ss.str()` might incur an additional copy when compared to `out<<ss.rdbuf()`, which might be an nontrivial overhead.

Comment: @Grizzly agree, `ss.str()` is a data copy, where `ss.rdbuf()` is a pointer to the data location

Comment: @Enigma Does it mean that replacement is more expensive than copy in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Confusingly, `ss.str()` does not do the same thing as `ss.str("")`:

`ss.str()` returns a copy of the underlying string, whereas `ss.str(const string&)` changes the underlying storage.

[Documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/str)